# Custom date doesnt work when there is a supress on the field

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a date field and it is of the format MM/DD/YYYY. I am changing the format of the field to DD.MM.YYYY in the crystal report on the Format Editor.

This works fine when there are no supress on the field. If there is a supress function enabled on the field on some conditions, the custom formatting doesnt work. Anyone knows why??

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you show your converting formula and also the supress formula?

Comment: i have posted some pictures to show how i am doing it, please take a look

Comment: what is supress condition? and are you placing the supress on the formatted field?

Comment: the supress condition is based on another field, for example lets say there is a field called qty. I am suppressing the display of date when the qty is 0. So the suppress condition looks like this, qty = 0

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the behaviour when field is supressed.. If you are interested in another solution try this:

Create a formula to convert the date field to required format and paste below code.

since your date format is `MM/DD/YYYY` and required format is `DD.MM.YYYY`

```
Split(ToText(CDate(Databasefield)),"/")[2]
&"."&Split(ToText(CDate(Databasefield)),"/")[1]
&"."&Split(ToText(CDate(Databasefield)),"/")[3];
```

Now write your required supress condition on this formula field